# how to add safeargs to project level Kotlin gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, arguments

Another user asked the same question, but I could not understand the solution. I also don't understand why the Android Developer page doesn't show a path according to this new version.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
}
dependencies {
    val nav_version = "2.4.2"
    classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")
}
}
```

These are the codes I need to add for navigation, but in the new project gradle;

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false }
```

These methods are written. Where should I write the Build Script and dependencies methods?

Comment: check official documentation for more details for the plugin -https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#groovy

Comment: Yes, I already got the codes written in the first line from here. I have reviewed in detail, but unfortunately I couldn't understand the solution.

Comment: Maybe you can link the question you didn't understand the answer for so we aren't just repeating the same answer. You can stick the `buildscript` block at the top of your file.

Answer (score 17):

add in build.gradle (Project):

```
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' version '2.5.1' apply false
```

And in build.gradle (Module) add:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false   
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' version '2.4.2' apply false
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 2):

With gradle.kts

**build.gradle.kts** (Project):

`id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin") version "2.5.1" apply false`

**build.gradle.kts** (Module) :

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
}
```